# Tetrahedron splitting/subdivision

Tags: discrete-geometry

Given a regular Tetrahedron *A* (i.e. each edge of *A* has same length), is it possible to split *A* into several smaller regular tetrahedra of equal size? I.e. smaller tetrahedra should completely fill volume of *A*, and they should not overlap.

This can be done in 2D with a triangle and square, and it can be done in 3D with cube (i.e. you can split cube into several smaller cubes of equal size). But I see no way to do same thing in 3D with tetrahedron.

If this can be done, how (how smaller tetrahedra should be positioned)?
If this cannot be done, is there a proof that this is impossible?

P.S. I'm not a mathematician, and this is not a homework, but I'd like to know how/if this can be done.

Comment: See also here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/131176/question-about-tetrahedron-decomposition/131372#131372

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is: No.  There is a somehwat rambling discussion [here](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/497054.html).  Let $B$ be a smaller tetrahedron that is jammed into the apex of $A$.  It fills the solid angle there completely.
Let $e$ be a base edge of $B$. Then one cannot fill the neighborhood of $e$ by gluing in
further regular tetrahedra along it.  One way to see this is that the dihedral angle of the tetrahedron is $\delta = \cos^{-1}(1/3) \approx 70.5^\circ$, and the dihedral angle along $e$ to be filled
is $\pi - \delta \approx 109.5^\circ$, which cannot be formed from copies of $\delta$.

Comment: Did not see Anton's answer while I was writing mine.  Mine is a version of his Answer 1.

Comment: Accepting this one because of the link to discussion.

Answer (score 15):

**Answer 1:** Look what happens on a face of the big tetrahedron where some edges of small ones come together: you have to make angle 180° out of some dihedral angles of the tetrahedra (which is about 70°) --- that is impossible.

**Answer 2:** There is the so-called [Dehn invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_invariant). If a polyhedron $X$ is split into a number of polyhedra $Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n$ then the Dehn invariant of $X$ is equal to the sum of the Dehn invariants of $Y_i$.

For the regular tetrahedron, the Dehn inveriant is nonzero and proportional to the length of a side.
Suppose you could split a regular tetrahedron with side $a$ into a number of tetrahedra with sides $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_n$. Then from the volume you have
$$a_1^3+a_2^3+\dots+a_n^3=a^3$$
and from the Dehn invariant you have
$$a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n=a.$$
It follows that there is no nontrivial splitting.

Comment: Anton, why does the first answer not work for cubes? Secondly, I am just curious whether subdivision of "1/3" of cube (halfs of three faces with one joint vertex) into equal congruent parts is possible.

Comment: The Dehn invariant of cube is $0$.

Comment: And for the first answer, the dihedral angle of a cube is 90 degrees, which evenly divides 180 degrees.

Comment: The volume should involve cubes of $a_i$s.

Answer (score 6):

It is however possible to split a regular tetrahedron into four smaller regular tetrahedra and one regular octahedron, and there are other possibilities based on the [tetrahedral-octahedral honeycomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral-octahedral_honeycomb).

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been pretty handily answered by Anton, but I figured I'd add another (somewhat ridiculous) proof to his list:

Answer 3:  Suppose that we had an infinite subdivision of regular tetrahedra.  Then we would also have a crystallographic lattice with tetrahedral symmetry, since this structure would have to tile across 3D space.  However, the classification of crystallographic lattices rules out this possibility!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_group

Comment: Classification of crystallographic lattices relies on some angles dividing $\pi$, so this is a convoluted way of phrasing Anton's Answer 1.